# Flutter: how to check if user is logged in by using flutter_secure_storage

Tags: flutter, authentication

I have this code for flutter_secure_storage:

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class SecureStorage {
  final FlutterSecureStorage storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  writeSecureData(String key, String value) async {
    await storage.write(key: key, value: value);
  }

  Future<String> readSecureData(String key) async {
    String value = await storage.read(key: key) ?? 'NULL';
    return value;
  }

  deleteSecureData(String key) async {
    await storage.delete(key: key);
  }
}
```

I want to use the read method for deciding if user is logged in (and then the secure storage has his email):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SecureStorage().readSecureData('keyUserEmail') == 'NULL'
          ? const Login()
          : MainPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

But is doesn't work and the app always begin at MainPage().

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `readSecureData` returns a future (not a string) so of course the comparision to `NULL` will always return false and you will end up at the main page. You cannot await that future in build, so you will have to use a `FutureBuilder` or embrace a state management solution (as there will presumably be many other bits of state you will introduce soon).

Comment: It's also not very Dart-y to have this `SecureStorage` class just to encapsulate these methods and a constant value. Make these method top level functions.

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks for the answer. What if I take off the Future<String>? I still get the same affect. And I don't understand why isn't Dart-y to put those methods in a separate class. Can you help me with a code snippet? Thanks!

Comment: https://dart.dev/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members (and I know you haven't marked them as static but if fact your code is worse because you keep having to instantiate an instance to call them). Remove the line `class SecureStorage` and the closing `}` and change your uses from `SecureStorage().readSecureData(` to `readSecureData(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `readSecureData()` method is asynchronous, but you are using it in a synchronous context. This means that the if statement is evaluating before the `readSecureData()` method has a chance to return a value.

To fix this, you can use a `FutureBuilder` widget to wrap your if statement. This will ensure that the if statement is only evaluated after the `readSecureData()` method has returned a value.

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class SecureStorage {
  final FlutterSecureStorage storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  writeSecureData(String key, String value) async {
    await storage.write(key: key, value: value);
  }

  Future<String> readSecureData(String key) async {
    String value = await storage.read(key: key) ?? 'NULL';
    return value;
  }

  deleteSecureData(String key) async {
    await storage.delete(key: key);
  }
}
```

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: SecureStorage().readSecureData('keyUserEmail'),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != 'NULL') {
            return const MainPage();
          } else {
            return const Login();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With this code, the if statement will only evaluate after the readSecureData() method has returned a value. If the user has logged in and the secure storage has their email, the app will start at the MainPage(). Otherwise, the app will start at the Login().

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @AJGottes Happy to hear that :)